# Place items that are not included in Array B at the end of Array A (In a File Tree Structure)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have 2 arrays of different types of objects. They both have a title under different names. I'd like to compare these two arrays by these names to move files that are not included in the `fileStructure` array at the bottom of the `files` array (when in a folder at the bottom of the folder).

```js
const files: FileType[] = [
    {
        info: { name: "fileThatsNotIncludedInArray2" },
        contents: [],
    },
    {
        info: { name: "fileThatsIncludedInArray2" },
        contents: [],
    },
    {
        info: { name: "fileThatsIncluded" },
        contents: [
            {
                info: { name: "chapterThatsNotIncludedInArray2" },
                contents: [],
            },
            {
                info: { name: "chapterThatsIncluded" },
                contents: [],
            },

        ],
    },
]
```

And I have the following second array:

```js
const filesStructure: FilesStructure[] = [
    {
        title: "fileThatsIncludedInArray2",
        chapters: []
    },
    {
        title: "fileThatsIncluded",
        chapters:
            [
                {
                    title: "chapterThatsIncluded",
                    chapters: []
                },
            ]
    }
]
```

The expected result would be something like this:

```js
const finalFiles: FileType[] = [
    {
        info: { name: "fileThatsIncludedInArray2" },
        contents: [],
    },
    {
        info: { name: "fileThatsIncluded" },
        contents: [
            {
                info: { name: "chapterThatsIncluded" },
                contents: [],
            },
            {
                info: { name: "chapterThatsNotIncludedInArray2" },
                contents: [],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        info: { name: "fileThatsNotIncludedInArray2" },
        contents: [],
    },
]
```

This is what I currently have but for some reason, it only places 1 of the items at the bottom and leaves out the rest:

```
export function placeUnIncludedElementsAtTheEndOfTheSortedArray(
    sortedArray: FileType[],
    fileStructure: FilesStructure[],
): FileType[] {
    for (const sortedFile of sortedArray) {
        const findInd = fileStructure.findIndex((fr) => {
            return fr.title == sortedFile.info.name
        })

        if (findInd == -1) {
            sortedArray.push(sortedArray.splice(sortedArray.indexOf(sortedFile), 1)[0])
        }
    }

    return sortedArray
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort by another array and move as last the values that are missing:

```
const sorted = ft.sort((a, b) => {
    const _a = fs.findIndex(s => s.title === a.info.name);
    const _b = fs.findIndex(s => s.title === b.info.name);
    return (_a == -1 || _b == -1) ? (_a == -1 ? 1 : -1) : (_a - _b);
});
```

The complete example is:

```
function changeStructure(ft: FileType[], fs: FilesStructure[]): FileType[] {
    // Sort by other array, move last missing values
    const sorted = ft.sort((a, b) => {
        const _a = fs.findIndex(s => s.title === a.info.name);
        const _b = fs.findIndex(s => s.title === b.info.name);
        return (_a == -1 || _b == -1) ? (_a == -1 ? 1 : -1) : (_a - _b);
    });
    // Recursive
    sorted.forEach(e => {
        const s = fs.find(s => s.title === e.info.name);
        if (s) e.contents = changeStructure(e.contents, s.chapters);
    })

    return sorted;
}
```